# Optional file validation with Formik/Yup

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik, yup

I want to validate file input if a file is selected, I found the solution for Formik/Yup but it validates even if file is not selected.

```
avatar: Yup.mixed()
    .test("fileSize", "File is too large", value => {
      return value && value.size <= FILE_SIZE;
    })
    .test(
      "fileFormat",
      "Unsupported Format",
      value => value && SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value.type)
    )
```

It triggers validation when I type in other inputs, I want to trigger it only if file is there since avatar is optional!

Comment: Can you share code sandbox? Formik [does not support file upload](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/45#issuecomment-314226595), so which method you used?

Comment: And did you tried [`notRequired()`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixednotrequired-schema) ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the test is returning `true` (meaning it validates) only when `value` exists. You have to add a condition to accept value when it doesn't exist (ie: is `null` or `undefined`).

I had the exact same problem and I solved like this:

```js
avatar: Yup.mixed()
  .test(
    "fileSize",
    "File is too large",
    value => !value || (value && value.size <= FILE_SIZE)
  )
  .test(
    "fileFormat",
    "Unsupported Format",
    value => !value || (value => value && SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value.type))
  )
```